# How to open permanent phones gallery through code on a folder

Tags: android

My app is creating a bunch of pictures and I want to open the folder with the user's gallery app so the user can watch, print, share them, or do whatever he likes.

**The standard solution:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(folder);
intent.setDataAndType(uri,"*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

Opens the folder in the phone's gallery, but if I click on an image, the galery closes instead of displaying the picture and staying alive.

**My closest solution**

```
Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
gallery.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Gallery");
startActivity(chooser);
```

Opens the full blown phones gallery app with all its abilities, but only on its root folder.

How can I open the full blown gallery app on a specific folder so that it doesn't close when an image is selected? A nice bonus would be the ability to open the pictures in the gallery as if the user had activated the slide show already.

Comment: "How can I open the full blown gallery app on a specific folder so that it doesn't close when an image is selected?" -- most likely, you don't. There are thousands of Android device models, shipping with hundreds of "gallery apps", plus hundreds more "gallery apps" available from the Play Store and elsewhere. There is no "ask a gallery app to let the user browse a folder" `Intent`, and even if there were, there is no guarantee that there is an app that honors that `Intent` on the user's device.

Comment: on windows, you would write: explorer.exe "path".  On Linux you would write caja "path" or nautilus "path". In general "appname" "path". Is there no equivalent in Andoid to pass in the path?

Answer (score 1):

> on windows, you would write: explorer.exe "path". On Linux you would write caja "path" or nautilus "path"

I am fairly certain that none of them open up a gallery app. Certainly `nautilus <path>` does not, and `explore.exe <path>` did not the last time I tried it on Windows (admittedly, a long time ago).

Moreover, "Linux" does not necessarily have `nautilus` or `caja` available. It is perfectly possible to have a Linux installation without either of them. Most servers have neither; my Ubuntu installation on this notebook does not have `caja`. Some Linux distributions might have something different to serve this role (e.g., whatever `xfce` uses). So, here we have a case where we have an operating system (Linux) that gets repackaged in different ways with different capabilities. Nobody with any sense would assume that *every* Linux environment has `nautilus` or `caja`.

> Is there no equivalent in Andoid to pass in the path?

TL;DR: Correct, there is no equivalent, particularly for a directory.

First, just as there is no requirement for Linux to have `nautilus` or `caja`, there is no requirement for an Android device to have a gallery app, a file explorer, etc. Only those things that are part of the core OS are pretty much guaranteed to exist. Android "distros" from device manufacturers therefore behave much like their Linux distro counterparts.

Second, Android has always been halfway towards the modern model of "stop thinking about files and folders". This is particularly true for folders, because there is no MIME type for a directory (the `file/*` hack is not universally agreed-upon).

Third, while there are many standard `Intent` structures, "view a directory's contents" is not among them.

So:

- Your `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` approach is not guaranteed to work even as well as you are seeing it, as [`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not take a `Uri`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT). Also, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is to allow the user to select a piece of content, and those activities that implement it may elect to go with a UI that reflects this.
- `ACTION_MAIN` is for the "front door" of the app. Typically, it is used with `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` for a home screen launcher icon. And, as [the documentation states, it does not take a `Uri` or any other form of input](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN).
- `ACTION_PICK` is akin to `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, but it does take a `Uri` as a parameter. If you use `image/*` as a MIME type, you might find some activity that can allow the user to pick an image from that directory. However, as with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, the UI may be tilted towards allowing the user to pick something. And, there is no requirement that the device have an app with an `ACTION_PICK` activity for a `file:` scheme and any MIME type, let alone `image/*`.
- `ACTION_VIEW` is how you ask to allow the user to view some content. However, this is not ideal for directories, because there is no agreed-upon MIME type. However, I would not be surprised if some file managers support the `file/*` approach. At the same time, there is no requirement for every Android device to have such a file manager, or any other app that handles this `Intent` structure.

Comment: Thanks for you exhaustive answer. What about a compromise: is it possible to check if there is an activity available that can handle file/*, then start this activity; else start a fallback solution (e.g. your own little file manager) ?

Comment: @Kenobi: Yes. Create the `Intent` that you would pass to `createChooser()`. Then, supply that `Intent` to `resolveActivity()` on `PackageManager`. If you get back `null` from `resolveActivity()`, there is no possible activity to handle the request, and so you can implement some fallback. If you get a non-`null` value, there is 1+ activities, and you can go ahead with your `createChooser()` work.